# Why are magento and magento-extension synonyms?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

Currently, [magento-extension](/questions/tagged/magento-extension) is a synonym of [magento](/questions/tagged/magento). So I regularly see people creating questions tagged [magento](/questions/tagged/magento) and [extension](/questions/tagged/extension) - normally I would retag them to use [magento-extension](/questions/tagged/magento-extension) instead but this tag is unavailable. I have to remove [extension](/questions/tagged/extension) as essentially meaningless instead, not really a great solution.

Is there a reason why these tags should be synonyms? There is a fair deal of Magento questions dealing specifically with extensions, so useless fragmentation cannot be it. Can the synonym be deleted to allow creating [magento-extension](/questions/tagged/magento-extension) as a new tag?

Answer (score -1):

The probable reason is that the [magento](/questions/tagged/magento) tag is a very low volume tag - ~10k questions out of a total of 3.6 million (0.002% of questions asked).

The number of questions on those synonyms was drastically much less and probably didn't really justify these sub-tags.

Comment: I am usually active in tags with significantly fewer questions than that and still consider sub-tags very useful - not everybody is interested in all aspects of a product/language.